# Which elo would you be playing when playing with a duo partner?

Tags: league-of-legends

In ranked matches, you have a choice of solo queuing (searching for match alone) or with another partner (duo queuing).

I was wondering, let's say I am in Gold or something higher, and my partner was in bronze or silver. Which elo would we be searching for match at? Will we be playing with primarily bronze / silver players, or gold or higher players?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you can only play with players a whole Tier above or below you(If you're Silver V you can play from Gold I to Bronze V).

Secondly, matchmaking creates an average of you and your premade friend elo, and then give it a boost (because you're premade), thus it means that if you're Silver V and your friend is Gold V, you would be going to play against a team with an Average of Silver II-II.

However since the premade "bonus" kicks in, it's likely that the enemy team will range from Gold V to Silver II.

Comment: 5 divisions... not leagues ;-)

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW Actually it's 1 tier and not 5 divisions. A gold 3 player can play with anyone between Silver 5 and Platinum 1.

Comment: wooooops xD 
That is actually what I meant, I just swapped the words =)

Comment: Could you edit your answer to reflect @Jutschge's correction? It's a common misconception and you're just perpetuating it. You can play with anyone 1 tier above or below you regardless of division.